# C++. Считать из файла размерность квадратной матрицы и элементы этой матрицы

Tags: c++

Как я понимаю делается с помощью fstream, но так и не разобрался как это сделать.
Исходный файл с размерностью и массивом должен быть таким, к примеру:

```
3
12 5 23
5 12 45
32 23 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ifstream fin("file.txt"); //открываем файл
int** arr; //матрица
int size;
fin >> size; //читаем размер
arr = new int*[size]; //инициализация
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) //массива
{
    arr[i] = new int[size];
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) //чтение элементов
        fin >> arr[i][j];
}
fin.close(); //закрываем файл
```

UPD: естественно, тут нет никаких проверок на несоответствие файла заданному формату, так что любая неточность и программа крашнется.

Comment: Тело второго цикла можно смело вносить в первый...

Comment: @Harry согласен, исправил

Comment: @SelfishCrawler спасибо